# FFMPEG images to timelapse

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to create a timelapse video with php and ffmpeg, I have all my images stored in a array, but the filenames are not wildcard conform - my images are named like this (from the webcam itself):

-P20030800260510.jpg
-P20030800370610.jpg

I found that command, but this won't work with my filenames.. any hints?

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pattern_type glob -i '*.JPG' -i DSC_%04d.JPG -s hd1080 -vcodec libx264 timelapse.mp4
```

Comment: Please elaborate *"won't work"* as it is too ambiguous. What is the actual problem?